# Problem running pylon webtests. ImportError and TestController is not defined errror

Tags: python, unit-testing, pylons, nosetests

I have directory structure as follow:
gnukhata/tests/functional.
In functional folder I have web tests files. Following is the sample test.

```
from gnukhata.tests import *

class TestVendorController(TestController):

def test_index(self):
    response = self.app.get(url(controller='vendor', action='index'))
```

After running this test file, gives following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/trial/runner.py", line 651, in   loadByNames
    things.append(self.findByName(name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/trial/runner.py", line 460, in findByName
    return filenameToModule(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/trial/runner.py", line 98, in filenameToModule
    return _importFromFile(fn)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/trial/runner.py", line 117, in _importFromFile
    module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fn, fd)
  File "test_vendor.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gnukhata.tests import *
exceptions.ImportError: No module named tests
```

Instead of gnukhata.tests if I write gnukhata then it shows the following error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/trial/runner.py", line 651, in loadByNames
things.append(self.findByName(name))
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/trial/runner.py", line 460, in findByName
return filenameToModule(name)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/trial/runner.py", line 98, in filenameToModule
return _importFromFile(fn)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/trial/runner.py", line 117, in _importFromFile
    module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fn, fd)
    File "test_vendor.py", line 3, in <module>
    class TestVendorController(TestController):
exceptions.NameError: name 'TestController' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my most simple configuration and let me know if it work:

```
import logging

from pylons import request, response, session, tmpl_context as c, url
from pylons.controllers.util import abort, redirect

from gnukhata.lib.base import BaseController, render
from gnukhata import model
import gnukhata.model.meta as meta
```

In the **init**.py:

```
from unittest import TestCase

from paste.deploy import loadapp
from paste.script.appinstall import SetupCommand
from pylons import url
from routes.util import URLGenerator
from webtest import TestApp
from pylons import config

import pylons.test

__all__ = ['environ', 'url', 'TestController']

# Invoke websetup with the current config file
SetupCommand('setup-app').run([pylons.test.pylonsapp.config['__file__']])

environ = {}

class TestController(TestCase):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wsgiapp = pylons.test.pylonsapp
        config = wsgiapp.config
        self.app = TestApp(wsgiapp)
        url._push_object(URLGenerator(config['routes.map'], environ))
        TestCase.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Tried above solution but didn't work out.So I wrote test.py :
     from pylons.controllers import WSGIController
     from pylons.templating import render_mako as render
     class TestController(WSGIController):
        def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
            return WSGIController.__call__(self, environ,start_response)
and saves the test.py file in the gnukhata/tests/functional directory.                                                   
Running tests with trial does not give any error.But with nosetests,it gives error as:ImportError: No module named pylons.controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an `__init__.py` in `gnukhata/tests` directory? If not, then `gnukhata.tests` is not recognized as a module and you can't import from it.

If such file does exist, could you post here the import statements in `gnukhata/tests/__init__.py` if any?

Comment: __init__.py is there in the gnukhata/tests directory. But still it gives the same import error.